# How to get Ctrl+return key binding for emacs in iTerm2 working?

Tags: keyboard, iterm, emacs

I have <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> key bound to a function that I use very often. This works when i run emacs in x-windows. But when I run emacs in iTerm2 control+return just has the effect of line-feed (i.e as if I have just hit enter without holding the control key down). i have tried different variation of this in emacs

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'duplicate-line)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-RET") 'duplicate-line)

(global-set-key  [(control return)] 'duplicate-line)

None of them seem to work in iTerm/emacs. I'm not sure if this a emacs terminal mode problem or a problem with iTerm2. I don't want to bind this to any other complex key sequence as I use this very often.

How to get Ctrl+return key binding for emacs in iTerm2 working?

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick test of emacs in iTerm2 and Terminal. Both see CTRL-RET as simply RET.

I did this with `CTRL-h k` to see what the key is bound to.

Comment: And? What did you conclude? I knew it was sees CRTL+RET as just RET. Simple way to test it is C-h k C-RET and you will see it shows help for RET. My question was how to fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I misread your question and so I didn't really answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map the CTRL-RET to anything you want by making a Profile. Editing the Profile.  In the **Profile** dialog box use the *Keys* tab to [image: edit the sequence] that gets sent when you press the keys.

I am not sure what sequence you need to send.

Hope this helps.